# Expectation at stopping time = Expectation at the beginning

Tags: martingales, expected-value, stopping-times

I hope I am not radically repeating a question here, but I have some issues understanding the martingale property at stopping times. Say I have a martingale $\{X_n,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and a stopping time $\tau$ which is finite:$$\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty) = 1$$
What do I need to show to be able to say:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{X}_{\tau\wedge n}\right] =  \mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\hat{X}_{\tau\wedge n}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{X}_\tau\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{X}_1\right]$$

I'll summarice the  questions that are arising:

- Do I need to explicitely show dominated convergence to exchange the limit and the expectation?
- Does a finite stopping time imply that $\tau$ is a bounded stopping time?
- Does the convergence of the martingale play an important role here?

I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: The answer is YES for the first question and NO  for second.

Comment: Thanks @KaboMurphy. How would you normally show the boundness of the stopping time and the dominated convergence? Is there a link to the almost sure or $L^p$ convergence? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are more things that enable us to change limit and expectation:

   $\bullet L_1$ convergence (or higher)

   $\bullet$ Dominated convergence ($X_{\tau\wedge n}$ can be bounded from above by an integrable function)

   $\bullet$ Monotone convergence ($X_{\tau\wedge n}$ is strictly positive)
2. A finite stopping time does not imply $\tau$ to be bounded. A bounded stopping time requires: $$\tau \leq c < \infty$$
   Having a finite stopping time yields for example:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tau \wedge n = \tau$$
3. As previously stated, $L_p$ converges implies that the limit can be exchanged with the expectation.

This answer is not really mathematical but will help noobs like me...